# How to get the ID of a child when mouseover parent

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I guess that my question is quite simple but I'm a real beginner in JavaScript and I can't find what I am looking for:

I am trying to get the ID of a li when mouse is over the nav or ul...
My HTML structure would be:

```
<nav><ul id="menu">
<li id="FirstLink">Link1</li>
<li id="SecondLink">Link2</li>
<li id="ThirdLink">Link3</li>
</ul></nav>
```

So my goal is to listen for a `mouseover` (and `mouseout`) event on each li, but a script with 10 listener (for 5 li) is too much dirty...

That's why I thought of a script like:

```
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
menu.addEventListener('mouseover', myFunction, false);

function myFunction () {
//something that get the ID of the <li> that is currently under the mouse and can put it inside a variable as "Link1"
}
```

But if there is a better solution, I will be happy to know it ! (I would like to stay in pure js)

Comment: What you're looking for is [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

Comment: here better place for this question http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the ID of the hovered element you need to use [**event.target**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target).
For that you need to pass `event` as a parameter in your function.
Then you can get the [**.id**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.id) attribute of that element.

```
function myFunction(event) {
    show_result.innerHTML = event.target.id;
}
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/A4yHn/)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
menu.addEventListener('mouseover', myFunction, false);

function myFunction (event) {
    var li = event.target;
    if( li.nodeName !== 'li' ) return;

    // do your stuff with li
}
```

Answer (score 1):

put the event on child elements only

```
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
for( var counter = 0; counter< menu.childNodes.length; counter++)
{
    menu.childNodes[ counter ].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
      alert( "id is  " + this.id  ); 
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me, but is there an particular advantage between this script and the short method with event.target above ?

Comment: @user2886084 has it worked? How does your script know that they need to take child id rather than parent id? Also if child 'li' has other children too, then this code will not be reliable at all. Since it will end up bubbling up from that smallest child element.

Comment: Oh I understood, of course my <li> are made for containing <a>, and as you said the script with event.target doesn't work (but it is easily solvable by putting the <a> around the <li>
But maybe I will end by using your solution :)

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/ssSnN/

and

```
$('#menu').children("li").on('mouseover', function() {
    var childID = $(this).attr("id");
    //YOUR ID WILL BE childID!
});
```

Comment: OP: *I would like to stay in pure js* = no jQuery

Comment: Whoops! I'll leave this here, just in case ;)

Comment: Was it a particulary bad way to say it ? My english isn't perfect as you see

Comment: No no, perfectly fine. I just didn't notice :)